# hmac in python not matching hmac in PHP and node

Tags: php, python, hmac, sha

I create an HMAC in Node like below:

```
const check = crypto.createHmac("sha1", "mysecret");
check.update(JSON.stringify("mybody"));
const digest = check.digest("hex");
```

Then I create the HMAC in PHP:

```
hash_hmac("sha1","mybody","mysecret")
```

Then I create the HMAC in Python 3

```
key = bytes("mysecret", 'utf-8')
message = bytes("mybody", 'utf-8')
digester = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest():
```

Then HMAC from Node and PHP match, no issues. But the HMAC from Python is always different and I cant figure out why.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have `JSON.stringify` which produces a string quoted with `"`, while your Python code does not.  Passing `check.update("mybody");` directly produced the same `'238aa706cad04c55a460b0c14b5e085f81a70f0b'` checksum in Node, thus identical to the Python version.

Comment: If you are checking a longer message, ensure that [the new line characters are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919154/hmac-value-not-consistent-in-python-and-php).

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply. I actually found my mistake. I bleach everything in this particular class, and also bleached the variable that contains the JSON object (I called it "word") in the example for simplicity's sake. When I removed the bleach the digests now match without having to change anything in node. Your ideas about the strings helped me spot my mistake, so thanks!!